# Linking to url with rmarkdown using Knit Word in Rstudio

Tags: r-markdown

Is there an easy way to link to a webpage in `rmarkdown` without displaying the link?

For example, putting "https://www.google.com/" in a `.rmd` file renders as the entire website, but I want something analogous to `<a href="https://www.google.com/">ABC</a>` instead.

The html method above, i.e., `<a href= ...` works when I knit to html, but it does not work when I knit to a word document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Markdown provides two ways to create a link as you mention (and I suppose that is supported on rmarkdown).

1. Markdown way:
       `[ABC](http://example.com)`
2. HTML way:
       `<a href="http://example.com">ABC</a>`
   The first way is *native* and the second way is supported since Markdown allows every HTML code.

Comment: Great, your #1 works, so I'll mark this as the solution.  Still #2 does not work for me with Knit Word, as I mentioned in the original post.