# IN R MARKDOWN, How Can I add a background image (HTML output)?

Tags: r, r-markdown

[image: The image should be instead of the black background]

I'm trying to put an image as background for my R markdown document (HTML output) Instead of the black background. I Was searching everywhere in the documentation on how to do this but I can't seem to find any answer as it's my first time working with R Markdown.

I can't seem to know how to put the background image and how to divide it that way so I can have my content in the middle

I'm also trying to attach a Hyperlink to tablist option,in the Picture[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XufiY.png) as you can see "Source" as for when I click on it, it directs me to an external page 
but `## [Source] ("github.com/example")` isn't working which was the syntax in the documentation.

[image]

this is my code till now .. 
I hope you can help me with these two questions, 
it's again : - How to set a background image to an HTML output on the whole page like the black background
 and how can I make the click on " Source " or TabItem directs me to an external link?

Thank you

````
    ---
title: "Title"
author: "Nessy"
date: "2 3 2020"
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
# {.tabset .tabset-fade}

## Analysis

## Source
````

Comment: Hello, have you looked at these regarding background, these may help? I know last two are for pdf, but process should be somewhat similar. https://rpubs.com/thaufas/555157 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534242/adding-background-image-to-r-markdown-rmd-file-for-pdf-document or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043187/adding-background-image-to-r-markdown-rmd-file-for-pdf-output

Comment: Thank you so much the first link worked, i should just divide it better, thank you, and can you help me with the Hyperlink please?

Comment: Hi Nessy, apology for the late reply. I hope you still need help. I assume you need help with setting up hyperlinks. You can do `[linktitle](url)`. Make sure there is no space between end of the bracket and beginning of parenthesis. More specifically it is `[Source]("github.com/example")` With no space.

Comment: hey sorry @ToadPitt , it sadly even so doesn't work, I made sure there is no space, but sadly still does nothing..

Answer (score 2):

Just posting the answers here so it can be marked as "answered." (Kindly mark this as answer when you're done and if this satisfies you).

1) Regarding background theme check this out: https://rpubs.com/thaufas/555157

2) Try `[github](someurl)` with no space in between. EDIT:
Regarding opening the link in markdown there try these links [R Markdown - Hyperlink outside Rmd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745926/r-markdown-hyperlink-outside-rmd-file) or [Linking to url with rmarkdown using Knit Word in Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024224/linking-to-url-with-rmarkdown-using-knit-word-in-rstudio).

Comment: [Source]("github.com/example") doesn't work sadly, good thing is that I don't see the link just written next to my Tab header anymore but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Well that sucks. Try this maybe, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745926/r-markdown-hyperlink-outside-rmd-file (first link is close to your problem) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024224/linking-to-url-with-rmarkdown-using-knit-word-in-rstudio or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706967/what-is-the-command-in-rmarkdown-to-source-and-display-the-code-from-an-existi ,rather than `opts_chunk....` use `read_chunk....` I may not be able to help you since I can't reproduce it in my machine. Sorry about that. Why don't you ask your peers for help?